# How to get id after filtering element's exact text using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get the `id` value of the `td` element within my `table` but only if its exactly "18:00" for example. I used `:contains` but its not exactly same `td`, so I went with `filter` as other question I read suggested and came up with this but it does not work. It returns `undefined`. Does anyone have a better solution?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var spa = $('#mainTable').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === "19:30";
  }).attr('id');
  alert(spa);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mainTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Arrival Hours</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="test1">19:30</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="test2">20:00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="test3">20:30</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You need to filter on the `td` cells, not the `#mainTable`

Comment: Also note you have an extra `</tr>` which can be removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate `td` element and fetch its `id` property. thus change the selector.

```
   var spa = $('#mainTable td').filter(function() {
        return $(this).text() === "19:30";
   }).attr('id');
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var spa = $('#mainTable tbody td').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === "19:30";
  }).attr('id');
  alert(spa);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mainTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Arrival Hours</th>
    </tr>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="test1">19:30</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="test2">20:00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="test3">20:30</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```